# When the Jägers discover Agatha in Girl Genius, to whom is Jenka reporting?

Tags: girl-genius

When the Jäger's first discover Agatha in Girl Genius, whom is Jenka [reporting to](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20050624) (or, at least, seeking instruction from — she may not be in direct contact with whomever she's mentioning anymore)?

[image: Jenka wants instructions, but from whom?]

Generally Jenka and "da boyz" refer to themselves as "wild" Jägers and don't report to anyone (with the exception of Agatha). Is there any indication from whom Jenka wants instructions? My guess is that she's waiting for instruction from Bill or Barry; but I don't see anything to support that (or indeed, any other theory).

Comment: I'd be curious to see if someone can find an answer from the Professors or in the comic. My impression was that it was from a Jager general (e.g., the as-yet-unseen one).

Comment: That could be; the fact that they're detached made me think they wouldn't ask the generals (and I sort of thought Jenka might _be_ the general that hadn't made contact).

Comment: Just noticed that one of the other generals referes to both missing generals as male; so not Jenka then.

Comment: Given the "muse of time" and the "time windows" which, it appears, allow not only vision, but passage of objects, it could be (future) Agatha that Jenka is reporting to.  It might also be a future general, a future Barry, or even a future Jenka.  The simplest answer is often, but not always, the truth.  In literature sometimes the slightly more complex answers are more fun.

Comment: Sorry for the double, but there is some non-zero chance that she might also be reporting to [Krosp](http://girlgenius.wikia.com/wiki/Krosp_I).  He has a knack for discretely and efficiently [gathering intelligence](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20140702#.VlpWJL_1Bj8).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There hasn't been any *definitive* answer to this in the comics, to date.

As of the storyline in December 2015, [Jenka has resurfaced](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20151209), claims that she's head of the "Mechanicsburg Diplomatic Corp", and mentioned that she carries a message from the Heterodyne spymaster (if you don't recognize Jenka in the new outfit, [Dimo - and the bear! - confirms her identity a page later](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20151211), although it's hard to see *him* in that outfit either).  Presumably the diplomacy bit is a front for further Heterodyne spy activity, but this does vaguely identify her chain of command as part of the espionage system of the family.

Which goes all the way back to when General Zog mentioned a [hidden general who keeps many secrets,](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20120516) and who will remain in the shadows. If wild Jagers like Jenka and Da Boyz report to anyone, this would be the most likely candidate, but until we meet (or reveal) that figure, that cannot be completely confirmed.

It should be mentioned that there is a pretty good candidate for "sneaky general" -

> in the form of the Unstoppable Airman Higgs.  He has way too many hidden connections to the Jagers in general for any normal fellow, and in one tiny slip of the tongue was implied to be an incognito Jager (which things like Mamma Gkika's fleshtone-at-will skin show is possible).  That doesn't make him a general, but there's also things like the Castle intelligence recognizing him, making him a bit more well connected than your average spy.  This doesn't make him Jenka's superior either, but it does fill in some gaps, as it were.

The original list of possibilities considered in this answer are: one of the Jager-generals, another Jager who was in charge of the "wild and/or exiled" groups, or a family member which if true would likely be Barry (the last one seen to be alive at any point, even if it was years ago, but unless he refused to return for some reason this is pretty unlikely, as finding any Heterodyne was the whole point of the wild Jagers). The only one of these that is even slightly disproven are the three Jager-generals with Klaus (Zog, Khrizhan, Goomblast), who had to be brought up to speed by Oggie in their meeting with Boris. That still leaves five other generals, one considered dead (Osk), only one of which we've met properly (Mama Gkika) and one other seen very briefly (the unnamed Red general, who I've seen fan-named Diabolous, and Gargantua), one apparently AWOL (Zadipok), and too much possibility for anything to be said for certain.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but didn't see anything to really support that either; what "slip of the tongue" are you referring to?

Comment: @Sam - here, last panel, http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20101018